# Asing static ip to azure container

Tags: azure, docker

I have deployed some services in azure instances, these containers will be turned on one or two days a week then turned off for the remaining days.

These containers have a Flask API that I'm accessing through the IP, the problem I'm having is that when I restart a container the public IP is not the same, is it possible to assign a static IP to each container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your issue, the Azure Container Instance is a managed service, so you cannot decide which public IP to use and also cannot decide which machine to host the instance. When you restart the instance, there are two possible events would happen.

One is the instance is started in the same machine, so the public IP will not change. Another is the instance is started in another machine, so the public IP will change into different with before. All these actions you cannot control.

The solution as I know is that you set the DNS name for the instance in the creation time. In this way, no matter the public IP change or not. The DNS name will not change, so you can access the instance via the DNS name without caring if the public IP change or not.